# How would i fetch a webpage on the server side and serve to client. (PHP)

Tags: php

Is there anyway you could request a webpage from a server and display the webpage to a user. It would essentially act as a proxy. Here is how it would work:

***Client sends the server running the script the website it wants*** > **server fetches website** > ***server displays the website to the client.***

Just to clarify the client is never contacting the website, the server running the PHP script is.

So, swiftly cutting to the chase **Is it possible?** **And if so how would you do it?**

Comment: what have you tried so far? there are multiple solutions for this...

Comment: @NormanM I have not tried anything yet. I spent 10 or so minutes looking around the internet and thought i would have better luck asking it here

Comment: @aidan I deleted my answer when I read your comment. Go try things by yourself and come back to edit your question if that doesn't work.

Comment: @ksjohn But isn't the whole point of this site to help start people coding?

Comment: @aidan Since you don't have the badge 'informed', I assume that you haven't read the tour page which explains what the point of the site is. How would you know it then ? For information : 

    'Don't ask about...

    - Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)'

Comment: @ksjohn But i did try and i couldn't find anything relevant so i asked here.

Comment: @aidan it is not to help people start coding, but helping people who started coding. in your case 10 minutes should have been enough to find the smallest possible solution inside the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2623

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

example usage

```
echo get_data('https://www.somedomain.xyz');
```

you can also do this via

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.somedomain.xyz")
```

Comment: This works, to an extent so is it possible that you can load the images since it looks on the server (running the PHP script) for the images.

Comment: In other words this script only serves the HTML, nothing else.

Comment: there is no way you can do this simply by php's built-in functions unless you download all images and put it somewhere on your server and replace urls.. its doable but complicated. 

Rather than ,I would suggest to use some ready-made proxy scripts which can serve your server as proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
    $contents=file_get_contents($url);
```

So you can be a little protected. Remember that is a risky function

Comment: How come it's risky?

Comment: First you can pass a file:

Comment: So someone could inject a script?

Comment: file://etc/passwd, second a person can see some internal server

Answer (score 0):

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com")
```

try it.

Comment: Same problem as @Muhammad Imran 's answer, it only serves the HTML, not CSS, JS etc..